# How to reset time picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, timepicker

How to reset time picker selected time using reset button in flutter?

I used .clear() but it does not worked.
And it does not clear after submission also.

Comment: Q: Show us your code? Your "TimeDatePicker" can actually be any of several completely different widgets. Q: What exactly does "reset" mean?  That you want the user to be able to push a button, and reset the timedatepicker to the current time and date?  Or something else?  SUGGESTION: See if this helps: https://codesinsider.com/flutter-timepicker-widget-example-tutorial/

Comment: Call setState it will reset it :p